# How can I make a WordPress custom function available in a Timber index page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, timber

I'm trying to convert my standard PHP WordPress theme to Timber/Twig and am having trouble getting any output from custom functions. This one in particular looks to see if the post has a Yoast Primary Term set, which allows you to specify a primary category for a post that has multiple categories.

I need to do this in within The Loop and most of the documentation talks about how to do it in a single page. I have a function like this in my functions.php:

```
function my_theme_get_post_category() {
    // regular list of categories set in WP
    list( $wp_category ) = get_the_category();
    // primary category set with Yoast plugin
    $primary_category = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_ID() );
    $primary_category = $primary_category->get_primary_term();
    $primary_category = get_category( $primary_category );
    // use only one or the other
    if ( is_wp_error( $primary_category ) || $primary_category == null ) {
        $category = $wp_category;
    } else {
        $category = $primary_category;
    }
    return $category;
}
```

Based on what I've read in the "Functions" section here (https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/WP-Integration#functions), I should be able to call this in my template with `{{ function('my_theme_get_post_category', post.ID) }}`, but that does not work.

I tried making `$postID` a required parameter of the function, but that also didn't help anything.

I also tried using the `TimberHelper::function_wrapper` and then calling it in the template with `{{ my_theme_get_post_category }}` but, again, that didn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Which version of Timber are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using the plugin, version 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

If you use `{{ function('my_theme_get_post_category', post.ID) }}`, then the function that you call needs to accept the argument that you pass. When you use…

```
function my_theme_get_post_category() {
    // Your function code
}
```

… then your post ID won’t be passed to the function. As you mentioned, you probably already tried to add the post id as a parameter:

```
function my_theme_get_post_category( $post_id ) {
    // Your function code
}
```

And nothing happened. That’s because your function uses functions that depend on The Loop, like `get_the_category()` or `get_the_ID()`. These functions **get the current post id** from global variables, which are not always set when you loop through posts in Timber.

When using Timber, you need to tell these functions to use a certain post id. If you look at the documentation for [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/), you see that there’s one optional argument that you can pass: the post id.

For the other function, `get_the_ID()`, you can simply replace it with the parameter `$post_id` that you pass to your function.

```
function my_theme_get_post_category( $post_id ) {
    // regular list of categories set in WP
    list( $wp_category ) = get_the_category( $post_id );

    // primary category set with Yoast plugin
    $primary_category = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', $post_id );
    $primary_category = $primary_category->get_primary_term();
    $primary_category = get_category( $primary_category );

    // use only one or the other
    if ( is_wp_error( $primary_category ) || $primary_category == null ) {
        $category = $wp_category;
    } else {
        $category = $primary_category;
    }

    return $category;
}
```